# Install Civicrm ESR on Buildkit wp-empty build

Tags: developer, civicrm-buildkit, esr

I am trying to set up a local development environment to test new extensions with an ESR version of CiviCRM (currently CiviCRM 5.45.6). To this end I use the [civicrm-buildkit-docker](https://lab.civicrm.org/michaelmcandrew/civicrm-buildkit-docker) projekt. So far I was successful to build recent version of CiviCRM based on wp-demo.
I have access to the .zip files of the ESR Versions of Civicrm. Therefore, my plan was to set up a build based on wp-empty and then to manually install these CiviCRM versions either with the user interface or by unpacking the zip file in the wp-content/plugins folder and to activate CiviCRM in the user interface.
With both approaches I was not successful:

1. Installing with the user interface I am redirected to a page stating: 'The link you followed has expired.'
2. Unziping the .zip file in the wp-content/plugins folder, I do see CiviCRM in the plugin list. If I then try to activate the plugin I get into following PHP-Errorrs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA. thrown in /buildkit/build/soziokultur/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php on line 37
```

```
CRM_Core_Exception: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA. in /buildkit/build/soziokultur/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php on line 37
```

Can anyone tell me, how to go about this or which way I could go to set up a development environment based on the ESR version of CiviCRM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: I think with the docker image you would run the [civibuild](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/civibuild/) command, rather than extracting manually. So something like:

```
civibuild create my-site --type wp-empty --civi-ver 5.57
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this did not work either. Using `--type wp-empty` I can succesfully build the environment but no CiviCRM is installed (as it is also supposed to be with wp-empty). If I replace the type by wp-demo e.g. `civibuild create testsite --type wp-demo --civi-ver 5.57.4` I get an error stating that the git branch could not be found. This is probably the case, because civibuild has no direct access to the ESR version of CiviCRM

Comment: does --civi-ver 5.57 work?

Comment: This did work!
Seems that my problem was not connected to installing ESR Version of CiviCRM but more about installing older version of CiviCRM. By try and error it turned out, that with CiviCRM vers < 5.52 I get a composer error, if I try to install them using civibuild. Would be interesting to learn, where this stems from, but thats probably another topic on its own.